# pass parameter value from one method to another aspx.net

Tags: asp.net

I need help here. Below is my code. In this line of code

```
dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["Kolicina"] = Convert.ToInt32(Label37.Text) + 3;
```

instead of 3 in next method this Label37.Text value should be incremented for one each time when user press the button.So I want this label value in next method to start to count from current value for one each time on button click.

```
      protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {


            var clickedRow = ((Button)sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
            var clickedIndex = clickedRow.RowIndex;

            decimal old = dtCurrentTable.Rows[clickedIndex].Field<decimal>("Kolicina");

            decimal oldIznos = dtCurrentTable.Rows[clickedIndex].Field<decimal>("VkIznos");
            decimal VkDanok = dtCurrentTable.Rows[clickedIndex].Field<decimal>("VkDanok");
            string Cena1 = dtCurrentTable.Rows[clickedIndex].Field<string>("Cena1");
            int TarifaID = dtCurrentTable.Rows[clickedIndex].Field<Int16>("TarifaID");

            newValue = old - 1; 
         // so i need label value from here to go in next method and increment++
           Label37.Text = newValue.ToString();
            decimal newIznos = oldIznos - Convert.ToDecimal(Cena1);

            dtCurrentTable.Rows[clickedIndex].SetField("Kolicina", newValue.ToString());
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[clickedIndex].SetField("VkIznos", newIznos.ToString());

    }


    protected void Button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["string2"].ConnectionString);

        conn.Open();

        ViewState["count"] = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["count"]) + 1;

        //  SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
        // sqlCmd.CommandText = "SupaSpanak";

        //  sqlCmd.Connection = conn;
        //    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT pkid,Artikal,Vid,EdMera,TarifaID,Cena1 FROM Artikli WHERE Artikal= 'N KREM SUPA OD SPANA]++' AND Cena1 = 130.00", conn);
        //brojac za kolicina 
        count++;
        decimal noofcount = count;
        Session["kolicina"] = noofcount;
        Label5.Text = Session["kolicina"].ToString();//ViewState["count"].ToString();//

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.Read())
        {
            Label9.Text = (string)reader["pkid"].ToString();
            Label3.Text = (string)reader["Artikal"].ToString();
            Label23.Text = (string)reader["Vid"].ToString();           
            Label10.Text = (string)reader["EdMera"].ToString();
            Label7.Text = (string)reader["TarifaID"].ToString();               
            Label4.Text = (string)reader["Cena1"].ToString();



            decimal cena = Convert.ToDecimal(Label5.Text);//kolicina
            decimal kolicina = Convert.ToDecimal(Label4.Text);//cena

            //vkIznos

            decimal mnoz = cena * kolicina;
            Label6.Text = mnoz.ToString();
            Convert.ToDecimal(Label6.Text);    
        conn.Close();

        DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["Markici"];
        if (Label37.Text == "0")
       {
        dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["Kolicina"] = Label5.Text;
       }
        if (Label37.Text != "0")
        {
            //Here this current value of Label37.text need to be incremented for one each time when button is clicked.
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["Kolicina"] = Convert.ToInt32(Label37.Text) + 3;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need viewstate,

```
    public int Counter
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["Counter"] != null)
            {
                return Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["Counter"]);
            }
            else
                return 0;
        }
        set { ViewState["Counter"] = value; }
    }



    protected void Button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //other codes..

        Counter = Counter + 1;
        if (Label37.Text != "0")
        {
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["Kolicina"] = Convert.ToInt32(Label37.Text) + Counter;
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you be more specific?

Comment: Sorry it works perfectly, I has other mistakes, thanks for help a lot!

Comment: Ok one question more, i have also another button like this, with same structure, but when i put here label with counter it start to count from previous label value.. that's  becouse that label value Label37.text which i get it should bring clicked index of button in dataTable..How to fix this?

Comment: I need here something to reset that value to 0 when user add new row and press btntest_Click

Comment: to reset you can use this; Counter = 0; and don't forget to accept the answer if It solved your problem.

Comment: there is a check icon under downvote which you should be able to use.

Comment: Solution is work for first two time of button click, on the third click doesn't work, is it expiring viewState or what?

Comment: viewstate does not expire